Do I need to apply for a new Vietnam E-Visa?
I am travelling to Vietnam in two days and I am in a bit of a confusing place, looking for some clarification.
In short, I have just realized my passport will expire before the required 6 months after departure from Vietnam. As such, I will renew my passport tomorrow (with same-day delivery) so that it complies with Vietnam's entry policy.
However, I had already obtained the E-Visa with my old passport. Do I need to apply for a new one? Since it takes 3 business days for it to be processed (and my flight is in two days) I am not sure if I should apply for a new EVisa or if the old one is still valid upon presentation of the old passport?

I have successfully flown to Vietnam with a (paper) visa in a passport with less than 6 months left plus a second passport.  However, the airline required me to fill out an indemnity form, and this was a long time ago (almost 20 years).

According to Vietnam's e-visa policy, your passport must be valid for more than 1 month from the visa expiration date.
In case you want to use the e-visa with your old passport, you must use the old passport to enter Vietnam. If you want to use the new passport to enter, you must apply a new one.
If you feel you don't have enough time to apply, you can use urgent visa services from travel agencies. They can issue your visa very fast up to 2 hours of a working day.
